# Top Active Pharmaceutical Ingredient Sales in US During 2016 (Current Year) Dataset(s)?

Tags: data-request, drugs

Seeking open dataset of Top active pharmaceutical ingredient sales/molecules sales data in US during current year.

Comment: I don't think private companies are going to publish point of sale data at such detail. Certainly not so actively or quickly.